# Getting input and assigning it to structures from an array of pointers, pointing to each structure.

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fill

I'm trying to assign input to a number of structures with an array of pointers, pointing to each allocated structure. I've been attempting to fill one structure and printing it, but keep getting errors and can't find out why. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

```
/* Structure declaration */

struct personCatalog {
  char name[50];
  char address[50];
  char cityState[50];
  char zipCode[7];
} ;

//function to fill structures

void getPerson (struct personCatalog *ArrayOfPointers[]);

   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

struct personCatalog *pointerArray[51]; 

getPerson(pointerArray);

 }

void getPerson (struct personCatalog *ArrayOfPointers[]){

struct personCatalog *tempPointer;

char stringCollector[512];

int maxNumberOfPeople = 51;
int num = 0;

while ((gets(stringCollector) != NULL) && (num < maxNumberOfPeople)) {

    tempPointer = (struct personCatalog *) malloc(sizeof(struct personCatalog));
    strcpy(tempPointer->name, stringCollector);
    gets(tempPointer->address);
    gets(tempPointer->cityState);
    gets(tempPointer->zipCode);

    ArrayOfPointers[num] = tempPointer;

    num++;

    printf("%s", ArrayOfPointers[num]->name);
    printf("%s", ArrayOfPointers[num]->address);
    printf("%s", ArrayOfPointers[num]->cityState);
    printf("%s", ArrayOfPointers[num]->zipCode);

}

 ArrayOfPointers[num] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Post them please.

Comment: why do you send  unusable pointers for the function, the pointers doesn't have any thing to use.

Comment: The error is at 'ArrayOfPointers[num] = tempPointer;.' The error says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)."

Comment: num is local, and you set it locally to a foreign variables. num get out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected it a little bit, try it out, but more work to do....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Structure declaration */

struct personCatalog {
  char name[50];
  char address[50];
  char cityState[50];
  char zipCode[7];
} ;
const int maxNumberOfPeople = 3; // was 51;

//function to fill structures

void getPerson (struct personCatalog *ArrayOfPointers[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  struct personCatalog *pointerArray[maxNumberOfPeople];

  getPerson(pointerArray);

}

void getPerson (struct personCatalog *ArrayOfPointers[]){
  struct personCatalog *tempPointer;
  char stringCollector[512];
  int num = 0;

  while ((num < maxNumberOfPeople) && (gets(stringCollector) != 0) ) {

    tempPointer = (struct personCatalog *) malloc(sizeof(struct personCatalog));
    strcpy(tempPointer->name, stringCollector);
    gets(tempPointer->address);
    gets(tempPointer->cityState);
    gets(tempPointer->zipCode);

    ArrayOfPointers[num] = tempPointer;


    printf("name      %s\n", ArrayOfPointers[num]->name);
    printf("address   %s\n", ArrayOfPointers[num]->address);
    printf("cityState %s\n", ArrayOfPointers[num]->cityState);
    printf("zipCode   %s\n", ArrayOfPointers[num]->zipCode);

    num++;
  }
  //ArrayOfPointers[num] = '\0'; this crashed at end of array
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a similar way to do it without using a global or const variable?

Comment: Haha. You can pass that maxNumberOfPeople as a parameter to the getPerson, just add an int as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough the code works for me with the necessary includes added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

However, this only holds for reasonable input - the code has a bit of room for improvement, but more on that later on.

The reason you don't see any output is that you are incrementing the index `num` after you assign the data to the struct, but before you print it - i.e. in the loop you are always dereferencing not yet assigned poiter, in other words garbage. It is only a question of time, when you try to dereference a null pointer (or anything not in your process' memory and segfault.

Now for the flaws:

- `malloc()` **always** comes with two things: a check for return value and a corresponding `free()`! The `free()` is missing, but I understand that there are/will be some other parts of code that could take care of that once the data is not needed any-more. However, you are not checking whether it doesn't return NULL (i.e. failed to allocate memory). That would bring your program down immediately (SEGFAULT due to null pointer dereference).
- `gets()` - I suggest reading the manpage for this function (if you are on Windows, look it up on the internet) - it doesn't guarantee any limits for reading data, hence you can easily overflow your buffer. Use `fgets()` instead. An alternative might be `scanf()` with width specifier to `%s`.
- `strcpy()` - the same as for `gets()`. Use `strncpy()` instead, unless you are dead-sure that it won't smash your data. Moreover, you are copying `char stringCollector[512]` into `char personCatalog.name[50]` - don't do that. It's inconsistent and if you base your bounds checks on the size of of the former, you are bound to have problems (rather sooner than later).

Last but not the least: an off-by-one error (it really is sometimes hard to get this right).

```
struct personCatalog *pointerArray[51];
...
int maxNumberOfPeople = 51;
if (num < maxNumberOfPeople)) {
    ...
    num++;
    ...
}
ArrayOfPointers[num] = '\0'
```

In the worst case, you are going to write behind `ArrayOfPointers` (to `ArrayOfPointers[51]` to be specific).

Use macros and decide whether you want to NULL-terminate the array:

```
#define MAXPEOPLE 50
struct personCatalog *pointerArray[MAXPEOPLE+1]; /* +1 for the NULL terminator */
if (num < MAXPEOPLE)) ...
```